# RailsCasts charts tutorial not displaying chart

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm following a tutorial on charting from RailsCasts but I"m running into a bit of a problem adding my own data. The chart does not display when I try to add my data.

I was able to get the chart to display with the example script from morris.js. I've set up my index.html.erb file with this line:

```
<%= content_tag :div, "", id: "stats_chart", data: {stats: @stats} %>
```

The div source is as follows:

< div data-stats="[{"id":1,"attendance":121,"salvations":12,"visitors":32,"offering":"234234.0","created_at":"2013-07-17T05:33:28.785Z","updated_at":"2013-07-17T05:33:28.785Z","campus_id":1,"date":"2013-07-14","time":"2000-01-01T19:00:00Z"},{"id":2,"attendance":1212,"salvations":1,"visitors":21,"offering":"123123.0","created_at":"2013-07-18T03:06:02.583Z","updated_at":"2013-07-18T03:06:02.583Z","campus_id":1,"date":"2013-07-07","time":"2000-01-01T17:00:00Z"},{"id":3,"attendance":234,"salvations":2,"visitors":24,"offering":"2345.0","created_at":"2013-07-18T03:15:12.613Z","updated_at":"2013-07-18T03:15:12.613Z","campus_id":1,"date":"2013-06-30","time":"2000-01-01T19:00:00Z"}]" id="stats_chart">

And my coffeescript file is:

```
jQuery ->
  Morris.Line
  element: 'stats_chart'
  $('#stats_chart').data('stats')
  xkey: 'date'
  ykeys: ['attendance']
  labels: ['attendance']
```

I'm guessing my issue is in the coffeescript but I can't figure out what. I'm using Rails 4 if that helps. What am I doing wrong? Or what do I need to change?

Comment: I'm going to assume it's because of turbolinks. I suggest you try this [gem](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in line 4 of the coffeescript

It should be:

```
data: $('#stats_chart').data('stats')
```

Comment: Somehow I missed it and couldn't see it until I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Your data set is invalid due to syntax error.

DIV's data attribute contains improperly nested double quotes `"` that are closing out the data set too early. Enclose the entire data set in double quotes, but use single quotes `'` inside of it for separating elements.

Instead of this:

```
data = "this["is", "incorrect"]" # syntax error
```

do this:

```
data = "this['is', 'correct']"
```